# how to manage undefined symbols in a shared library

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries

I have a shared library which has undefined symbol

```
JNI_CREATEJavaVM
```

Is there any way i can include the external dependency or tell the compiler to ignore the symbol?

Comment: Compiler (and linker) does not check shared libraries that are already compiled when you link something against them. If you're *building* this library, not just *have* it, then yes, you should add a dependency (typically `-l` option to `gcc`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) I think (telepathy mode on) that you are trying to build libdvm.so and get hack around Java NDK, that do not exposes JNI_CREATEJavaVM function. Don't do it. Go and google why not and what are other possible solutions.

2) Since your question sounds like "how to manage", I will present my favorite way to manage such things -- by introducing fake weak definitions. Lets step out building shared libraries, since there are really don't matter what do we building. Consider we have some undesym.c file with code:

```
int
main(void)
{
  JNI_CREATEJavaVM();
  return 0;
}
```

It produces `` undefined reference to `JNI_CREATEJavaVM' `` error.

Lets add to linking module fakeone.c with fake weak stub:

```
#include "assert.h"

int  __attribute__((weak))
JNI_CREATEJavaVM(void)
{
  assert(0 == "stub JNI_CREATEJavaVM is not for call");
  return 0;
}
```

Now everything links ok, but on stub call produces runtime assertion

`` a.out: fakeone.c:6: JNI_CREATEJavaVM: Assertion `0 == "stub JNI_CREATEJavaVM is not for call"' failed ``

But why is it weak? Because consider somebody links it with real JNI_CREATEJavaVM code. For example try goodone.c

```
#include "stdio.h"

int
JNI_CREATEJavaVM(void)
{
  printf("JNI_CREATEJavaVM Ok\n");
  return 0;
}
```

And compile `gcc undesym.c goodone.c fakeone.c`
Now correct definition overwrites weak stub and you will get correct message.

Surely you must try to avoid this technique, but it helped me several times.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can tell the compiler to ignore the symbol.

From `man ld`,

--unresolved-symbols=method

Determine how to handle unresolved symbols. There are four possible values for method:

```
   ignore-all
       Do not report any unresolved symbols.

   report-all
       Report all unresolved symbols.  This is the default.

   ignore-in-object-files
       Report unresolved symbols that are contained in shared
       libraries, but ignore them if they come from regular object files.

   ignore-in-shared-libs
       Report unresolved symbols that come from regular object
       files, but ignore them if they come from shared libraries.
```