# I have a question about C library compilation

Tags: c, linux

I have some `C` source file `func1.c、func2.c、main.c` and a `C` header file `func1.h、func2.h` as follows:

```c
// func1.h
#ifndef _FUNC1_H
#define _FUNC1_H
void show(int* nums, int n);


#endif
```

```c
// func1.c
#include "func1.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void show(int* nums, int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", nums[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

```c
// func2.h
#ifndef _FUNC2_H
#define _FUNC2_H
void show2(void* nums, int len);


#endif
```

```c
// func2.c
#include "func1.h"

void show2(void* nums, int len)
{
    int* array = (int*)nums;
    show(array, len);
}
```

```c
//main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
typedef void (*SHOW2_FUNC)(void* nums, int len);
static void * handler = NULL;

void* get_func(const char* libname)
{
    handler = dlopen(libname, RTLD_LAZY);
    if (handler == NULL)
    {
        printf("open lib: %s error! \n", libname);
        return NULL;
    }

    SHOW2_FUNC show_func = dlsym(handler, "show2");
    if (show_func == NULL)
    {
        printf("can't find function: %s ! \n", "show2");
        return NULL;        
    }

    printf("find funcion successful, address is %p \n", show_func);
    return show_func;
}

int main()
{
    int nums[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    
    SHOW2_FUNC pf_show = get_func("./libfunc2.so");
    pf_show(nums, 5);
    dlclose(handler);
    return 0;
}
```

I use the following `gcc` command to compile `func1.c`,and I got static link library `libfunc1.a`

```bash
gcc -c func1.c -o func1.o
ar crv libfunc1.a func1.o
```

And then, I use the following `gcc` command to compile `func2.c`, and I got dynamic link library `libfunc2.so`

```bash
gcc -c func2.c -o func2.o
gcc func2.o -o libfunc2.so -shared -fPIC libfunc1.a
```

Finally, I use the following `gcc` command to compile `main.c`, and I got executable file `main`

```bash
gcc -o main main.c -ldl
```

Execute `main`, the results are as follows:

```
find funcion successful, address is 0x7fdadcde069a 
1 2 3 4 5
```

The result of running the `ldd libfunc2.so` command is as follows:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffd8e91000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd687be0000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd688200000)
```

But, if I use the following `gcc` command to compile `func2.c`. No errors were reported during compilation.

```bash
gcc -o libfunc2.so -shared -fPIC libfunc1.a func2.o  #  Place the file func2.o at the end
```

Execute `main` again, the results are as follows, and I got a run error.

```bash
find funcion successful, address is 0x7f6b577e05ba 
./main: symbol lookup error: ./libfunc2.so: undefined symbol: show
```

The result of running the `ldd libfunc2.so` command is as follows:

```
statically linked
```

Bisides, I compile `func1.c` into a dynamic link library `libfunc1.so`, and use it to compile `libfunc2.so`. Compile commands are as follows:

```bash
gcc func1.c -o libfunc1.so -shared -fPIC
gcc -o libfunc2.so -shared -fPIC -L. -lfunc1 -Wl,-rpath=. func2.o
```

Execute `main` again, the results are as follows, and I got a run error.

```bash
find funcion successful, address is 0x7f6b577e05ba 
./main: symbol lookup error: ./libfunc2.so: undefined symbol: show
```

Why would a different order lead to the above result? Why is there no error at compile time? Thank you for reading.

Comment: func2.c should include func2.h.

Comment: @Lundin I want to use function `show` defined in `func1.c`, so I includes  `func1.h`

Comment: fun fact: func2.h is unused and can be removed. For starters, you may want inspect `LD_DEBUG=all ./main`. I am not able to reproduce the last case - it works for me. I am also not able to reproduce `The result of running the ldd libfunc2.so command is as follows statically linked` and it would be really odd. `libfunc2.so` is a shared library for me after executing `gcc -o libfunc2.so -shared -fPIC libfunc1.a func2.o`. Consider creating a Makefile with  like list of commands to be reproducible. Also, consider adding numbers, or splitting, there are actually two questions here..

Comment: Code intended to be included in a shared library should be *compiled* with `-fPIC`, or maybe `-fpic`.  The resulting object files are different from those built without either of those options.  You need those when linking the shared library, too, but you cannot defer using those options until then.

Comment: #1 when linking, the order does matter #2 when linking a shared object, use option `-Wl,-zdefs`

Answer (score 1):

I created the files and used the following makefile with commands from your post:

```
all:
    gcc -c func1.c -o func1.o
    ar crv libfunc1.a func1.o
    gcc -c func2.c -o func2.o
    gcc func2.o -o libfunc2.so -shared -fPIC libfunc1.a
    gcc -o main main.c -ldl
    ./main || :
    ldd libfunc2.so

    gcc -o libfunc2.so -shared -fPIC libfunc1.a func2.o
    ./main || :

    ldd libfunc2.so
    gcc func1.c -o libfunc1.so -shared -fPIC
    gcc -o libfunc2.so -shared -fPIC -L. -lfunc1 -Wl,-rpath=. func2.o
    ./main || :
```

it results in the following output:

```
gcc -c func1.c -o func1.o
ar crv libfunc1.a func1.o
r - func1.o
gcc -c func2.c -o func2.o
gcc func2.o -o libfunc2.so -shared -fPIC libfunc1.a
gcc -o main main.c -ldl
./main || :
find funcion successful, address is 0x7fb8d951c129 
1 2 3 4 5 
ldd libfunc2.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe1a7e7000)
        libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f24dab42000)
        /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f24dad72000)
gcc -o libfunc2.so -shared -fPIC libfunc1.a func2.o
./main || :
find funcion successful, address is 0x7f9a49030109 
./main: symbol lookup error: ./libfunc2.so: undefined symbol: show
ldd libfunc2.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc92996000)
        libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f245acd8000)
        /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f245af08000)
gcc func1.c -o libfunc1.so -shared -fPIC
gcc -o libfunc2.so -shared -fPIC -L. -lfunc1 -Wl,-rpath=. func2.o
./main || :
find funcion successful, address is 0x7fab12301109 
1 2 3 4 5
```

I am running on ArchLinux gcc13.2.1 ld.so2.38.

---

> ```
> gcc -o libfunc2.so -shared -fPIC libfunc1.a func2.o  #  Place the file func2.o at the end
> ```
>
> Execute main again, the results are as follows, and I got a run error.
>
> ```
> find funcion successful, address is 0x7f6b577e05ba 
> ./main: symbol lookup error: ./libfunc2.so: undefined symbol: show
> ```

Yes. If you take a look at libfunc2.so, you will see that:

```
$ nm ./libfunc2.so 
.....
                 U show
0000000000001109 T show2
0000000000004010 d __TMC_END__
```

Symbol `show` is undefined. Why is that? Because from https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html :

> ```
>        The linker will search an archive only once, at the location
>        where it is specified on the command line.  If the archive
>        defines a symbol which was undefined in some object which
>        appeared before the archive on the command line, the linker
>        will include the appropriate file(s) from the archive.
>        However, an undefined symbol in an object appearing later on
>        the command line will not cause the linker to search the
>        archive again.
> ```

In short, only used symbols from archive are used at the time they are encountered. So `func2.o` has to be before `libfunc1.a` on the command line. Or, use `--whole-archive` option. See also https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html .

---

> The result of running the ldd libfunc2.so command is as follows:
>
> ```
> statically linked
> ```

I believe you made an error here, I am not able to reproduce. For me, the output at this point is:

```
ldd libfunc2.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdc39f3000)
        libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6613201000)
        /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6613431000)
```

---

> ```
> gcc func1.c -o libfunc1.so -shared -fPIC
> gcc -o libfunc2.so -shared -fPIC -L. -lfunc1 -Wl,-rpath=. func2.o
> ```
>
> Execute main again, the results are as follows, and I got a run error.
>
> ```
> find funcion successful, address is 0x7f6b577e05ba 
> ./main: symbol lookup error: ./libfunc2.so: undefined symbol: show
> ```

Once again, I am not able to reproduce. For me, at this stage, the executable links using `RPATH=.` with `libfunc1.so`, like the following:

```
$ LD_DEBUG=all ./main 2>&1 | grep show
     63682:     symbol=show2;  lookup in file=./libfunc2.so [0]
     63682:     binding file ./libfunc2.so [0] to ./libfunc2.so [0]: normal symbol `show2'
     63682:     symbol=show;  lookup in file=./main [0]
     63682:     symbol=show;  lookup in file=/usr/lib/libc.so.6 [0]
     63682:     symbol=show;  lookup in file=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 [0]
     63682:     symbol=show;  lookup in file=./libfunc2.so [0]
     63682:     symbol=show;  lookup in file=./libfunc1.so [0]
     63682:     binding file ./libfunc2.so [0] to ./libfunc1.so [0]: normal symbol `show'
```

---

> Why would a different order lead to the above result?

Because linker searcher for symbols in linked archives *in order* of the command line parameters.

> Why is there no error at compile time?

The magic of shared libraries is that you they are resolved at runtime, not compile time. So no compile time errors. [You can ignore unresolved symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555933/how-to-manage-undefined-symbols-in-a-shared-library) - it's just a sanity check.

Comment: “I believe you made an error here, I am not able to reproduce. For me, the output at this point is:” I execute the follow command  in WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux).
```bash
gcc -o libfunc2.so -shared -fPIC libfunc1.a func2.o
ldd libfunc2.so
```
The result is still `statically linked`. I will try on other system.

Comment: In WSL, gcc version is `gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)` and ld version is `GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.30`

Answer (score 0):

### It matters where you put your files for a linker to resolve.

It is a general rule that you put files where `symbol` is referenced BEFORE file where `symbol` is defined.

To understand the reason of error you have to understand how linker works:

- All files passed to linker processed from left to right
- Linker collects undefined symbols from files to the pool of undefined
  symbols
- If object from archive doesn’t resolve any symbols from pool of
  undefined symbols, then it dropped

In your case:

```
gcc -o libfunc2.so -shared -fPIC libfunc1.a func2.o
```

You basically put archive library where symbol `show1()` is defined before object file where it is referenced. **So your `libfunc1.a` doesn't resolve any symbols and is dropped.**

And from [GCC -l library option:](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)

It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order they are specified.

Thus, `foo.o -lz bar.o`

searches library `z` after file `foo.o` but before `bar.o`. If `bar.o` refers to functions in `z`, those functions may not be loaded.